# How can I print each row in a text file in order?

Tags: python

This is my improved code

```
w, r = 0,0 

with open("questions.txt", "r", newline="") as file:
    mycsv = csv.reader(file)
    for question in list(mycsv):
        print(question[0], "\n", question[1], "\n", question[2], "\n", question[3])
        answer1 = input("Answer 'a','b' or 'c': ")
        if answer1.strip() == question[4].strip():

            if answer1 != (question[4]):
                print("---------------------------------------------------")
                print("Correct!")
                print("---------------------------------------------------")
                w = w + 1
                r = r + 1


            elif answer1 == (question[4]):
                print("---------------------------------------------------")
                print("Incorrect!")
                print("---------------------------------------------------")
                w = w + 1


        elif w == 3:
            print("Game over")
            print("You got",r,"right out of 3")
```

if the user answer is wrong the code will not print incorrect, it will just move to the next question. Also after 3 questions are finished it prints a list index out of range error.

Comment: Hello @Felix. Nice to have you around. Thank you for your question. At present there is a bit of work to do for you. Please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve otherwise chances are good, that your question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the same file each time it loops. Instead you want to open the file one, and loop over the lines in the CSV.  (Remove the while loop entirely)

```
import csv

w = 0
r = 0


with open("questions.txt", "r", newline="") as file:
    mycsv = csv.reader(file)
    for question in list(mycsv):
        if len(question) != 5: 
            continue
        print(question[0], "\n", question[1], "\n", question[2], "\n", question[3])
        answer1 = input("Answer 'a','b' or 'c': ")
        if answer1.strip() == question[4].strip():
            print("---------------------------------------------------")
            print("Correct!")
            print("---------------------------------------------------")
            w = w + 1
            r = r + 1

        else:
            print("---------------------------------------------------")
            print("Incorrect!")
            print("---------------------------------------------------")
            w = w + 1

if w == 3:
    print("Game over")
    print("You got", r, "right out of 3")
```

Example input file:

```
Correct is a, a, b, c, a
Correct is b, a, b, c, b
Correct is c, a, b, c, c
```

Example output:

```
Correct is a 
  a 
  b 
  c
Answer 'a','b' or 'c': a
---------------------------------------------------
Correct!
---------------------------------------------------
Correct is b 
  a 
  b 
  c
Answer 'a','b' or 'c': b
---------------------------------------------------
Correct!
---------------------------------------------------
Correct is c 
  a 
  b 
  c
Answer 'a','b' or 'c': a
---------------------------------------------------
Incorrect!
---------------------------------------------------
Game over
You got 2 right out of 3
```

Comment: Thanks your code was perfect however it has left me with a couple of errors.  The first is when i finish my code it gives a list index out of range error. It also does not print the incorrect if the input is wrong

Comment: @FelixWheeler going to guess the first one is that there is a newline at end of file (trying to read a blank line as a question), added check for that ^. Also added entire code block, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `while` loop. And I suggest you use a function to check each answer :

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    content = file.readlines()
for line in content:
    check_quiz() #function to ask the question and check the answer
```

Since you're using Python3, use `\n` like so:

```
print("----\n"+ "Incorrect!\n"+ "---")
```

More expressive variable names would help as well. There are quite a few other things that can be improved in your code, check Stackoverflow's [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or a tutorial for an idea.